# Get Bootstrap Icons to Render

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to use this bootstrap signup template [here](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/extended/registration/), but when I render it the icons for the user, email, password, etc. are missing.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<section class="vh-100" style="background-color: #eee;">
  <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-11">
        <div class="card text-black" style="border-radius: 25px;">
          <div class="card-body p-md-5">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-5 order-2 order-lg-1">
                <p class="text-center h1 fw-bold mb-5 mx-1 mx-md-4 mt-4">Sign up</p>
                <form class="mx-1 mx-md-4">
                  <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                    <i class="fas fa-user fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                    <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                      <input type="text" id="form3Example1c" class="form-control" />
                      <label class="form-label" for="form3Example1c">Your Name</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                    <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                    <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                      <input type="email" id="form3Example3c" class="form-control" />
                      <label class="form-label" for="form3Example3c">Your Email</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                    <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                      <input type="password" id="form3Example4c" class="form-control" />
                      <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4c">Password</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                    <i class="fas fa-key fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
                    <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                      <input type="password" id="form3Example4cd" class="form-control" />
                      <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4cd">Repeat your password</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-check d-flex justify-content-center mb-5">
                    <input class="form-check-input me-2" type="checkbox" value="" id="form2Example3c" />
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="form2Example3">
                      I agree all statements in <a href="#!">Terms of service</a>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mx-4 mb-3 mb-lg-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Register</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-6 col-xl-7 d-flex align-items-center order-1 order-lg-2">
                <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-registration/draw1.webp"
                  class="img-fluid" alt="Sample image" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

When I render it via the code snippet plugin on stack overflow it just removes the icons entirely, but if you look at the example at the link you can see the icons, but what I get on my project is broken image indicators in place of the icons. It's not clear to me from the HTML though where the icons are loaded (unlike e.g. the image where it's super clear). How do I get it to correctly render the icons?

Answer (score 0):

The icons you are trying to use i think are part of **MDBootstrap** that is a UI kit built on **Bootstrap**, so if you want the icons to render properly you got to include **MDBootstrap** in your project.

If you don't want to use that you can always use official **Bootstrap 5** icons (https://icons.getbootstrap.com/,   https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/extend/icons/) or the **recommended** by Bootstrap developers **Fontawesome** icons (https://fontawesome.com/)